# How to move cursor to row in sheet based on Userform textbox input?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a scheduling tool for some work orders, and I already have an excel sheet filled out with the names of those orders. I would love to have a user open up a Userform, and enter the name of the order into a textbox, and have the cursor on the sheet move to the row corresponding to that order. Is there a way I can do this?

I've thought about using a listbox instead, but would like to use the textbox if at all possible.

Comment: You can use TextBox_AfterUpdate, and code to Range.Select

Comment: Yes, yes there is.  What have you tried so far?  Ideally StackOverflow would be correcting an issue/error on your part, not so much having a subjective discussion.  At this point your post is `Too Broad` because there are numerous ways to go about this task, though the use of `.Select` is pretty static in them all.

Comment: How can I get my code to search for the specific string/number of the work order so that I select the correct row?

Comment: I have tried using Range.Find in TextBox_AfterUpdate() but was having trouble with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a userform for a single field seems a bit much, how about an InputBox, something like this:

```vb
Sub findOrder()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet Name Here")
Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'get last row at column A - assuming is populated

restartOrder:
Dim strOrder As String: strOrder = InputBox("Please input your order name", "Let's find the order")
Dim rngOrder As Range

Set rngOrder = ws.Range("A1:A" & lRow).Find(strOrder) 'Find the order, assuming they are in column A

If Not rngOrder Is Nothing Then '
    rngOrder.Select 'Select the order range
Else
    Dim answer As Integer: answer = MsgBox("Order wasn't found, want to try again?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Not found")
    If answer = vbYes Then
        GoTo restartOrder 'restart the search
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

EDIT: added some better handling on order not found.

EDIT2: add a userform option too... add a `CommandButton` and a `TextBox` to your userform:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    findOrder TextBox1.Value
End Sub

Sub findOrder(strOrder As String)

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet Name Here")
Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'get last row at column A - assuming is populated

restartOrder:
Dim rngOrder As Range

Set rngOrder = ws.Range("A1:A" & lRow).Find(strOrder) 'Find the order, assuming they are in column A

If Not rngOrder Is Nothing Then '
    rngOrder.Select 'Select the order range
Else
    Dim answer As Integer: answer = MsgBox("Order wasn't found, want to try again?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Not found")
    If answer = vbYes Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Unload Me
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: There will be more I am having my code perform than just the cursor movement, which is why I opted for the userform. This seems like exactly what I want however! Is there a way to use this in R1C1 format? Especially the line including the Range.Find?

Comment: I`ve added a version with a userform too, see updated answer. As for the R1C1 format... ? not quite sure what you mean... you would normally only use that to add formulas in R1C1 format, can't think of other reason. If you can explain what else you are trying to achieve, i might be able to help.

Comment: I actually think you've answered all my questions! I have always used the R1C1 format, just because I learned VBA using it, but I think I will abandon it for the default A1 formatting instead.

Comment: Unless you are using the workbook exclusively in R1C1 format, is better to use the actual ranges. If you get use to it, you will eventually forget about the letters and just use the numbers to refer to ranges, i.e.`ws.Cells(5, 3)` = `C5` , or `ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(5, 3))` = `A1:C5` . Working with numbers makes it for easier reference to ranges in loops.